# Set placeholder value in paper-input (Polymer 1.0)

Tags: polymer

I'm working on a project with Polymer 1.0. I have a `<paper-input>`, and I want to set the placeholder value.

I tried setting `value`:

```
<paper-input value="default value"></paper-input>
```

but it doesn't change the placeholder. I also tried `label`:

```
<paper-input label="default value"></paper-input>
```

but that also doesn't change the placeholder. How do I set the placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`<paper-input>.placeholder`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/paper-input/paper-input#property-placeholder) like this:

```
<paper-input placeholder="Enter a number"></paper-input>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <paper-input placeholder="Enter a number"></paper-input>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/wgdVLV?editors=1000)